# JavaFX Deploying with other JavaFX projects

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, javafx-8

I have two JavaFX projects.

- Sub Project : AnchorPane with a Label. (and a controller attached to
  it)
- Main Project : AnchorPane with a Button. You click it, and it will
  bring up a new Window with Sub Project on it.

So Sub Project and Main Project both have their own fxml file and controller.

When I compile the Main Project using NetBeans, it works perfectly fine. 
However, once I deploy the Main Project to other computer, it gives me an error message "The system cannot find the file specified"

I think the problem is that I use absolute path of sub project's fxml location when I pop up the 
sub window. I've been trying to get the path of fxml in Jar file from external library, 
but I couldn't find any solution. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my code opening a new sub project window in 
Main Project's Controller

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction() throws IOException() {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File("D:/SubProjAddress/SubProject.fxml").toURI().toURL());
    Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

I'm using Java 8, netbeans.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I found an Oracle webpage "5.8.3 Packaging Complex Applications", and it says "For the double-clickable JAR file, consider repackaging everything into a single giant JAR file and loading native libraries and data files from inside the JAR." But, I have no idea what it means..

Comment: `new File("D:/SubProjAddress/SubProject.fxml")` is the absolute path of the fxml. You need to use a relative path.

Comment: I've tried ("../SubProjAddress/SubProject.fxml") but it only works using netbeans compiler

Comment: Try something like this `(/packagename/SubProject.fxml)`

Comment: (/packagename/SubProject.fxml) doesn't work even with NetBeans compiler. It just directs me to D:/SubPakage/SubProject.fxml

Comment: I found an ugly walk around; just put two projects in one folder and use relative path. But that is not the deployment I want.

Comment: Are you trying to load the fxml in your `SubProject` from your `MainProject` ?

Comment: I'm just tring to do the thing above. When MainProject's button is clicked, a new window with SubProject in it pops up.

Comment: So the MainProject loads SubProject's fxml in it's new stage. And everything like initializing the SubProject's fxml will be managed by SubProject's Controller, not main project's controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem, so I post it here for future reference.

If you have MainProject containing SubProject, and you want to load SubProject's fxml to your MainProject, you need to load the SubProject's fxml from the .jar file of the SubProject. 
The code above seems like loading SubProject's fxml from your src file, not .jar file, and that is causing the problem.

To load fxml file from jar file, just use  Class.getResource() instead of the above code.

for example,

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File("D:/SubProjAddress/SubProject.fxml").toURI().toURL());
Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
```

becomes

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/subpackage/SubProject.fxml"));
```

Using this, I could deploy my application containing multiple projects without any problem.